# Redirect standard output to nul is not working in batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

**My Situation**

I have a Windows Scheduled Task that starts Bamboo on user login by running `C:\_atlassian\Bamboo\BambooConsole.bat`. This works fine but opens up a command prompt that has a lot of continuous standard output. I would like to stop this from happening.

**My Attempted Solution**

Instead of running `C:\_atlassian\Bamboo\BambooConsole.bat` directly, I created a new file `BambooConsoleSilent.bat` to run which is just...

`call C:\_atlassian\Bamboo\BambooConsole.bat > NUL`

However when run it still prints to console as seen below.

**Question**

How can I ensure there is nothing printed to console?

Or even better, can I run the original `BambooConsole.bat` without opening up any command window?

[image: example]

Comment: The messages are coming out on `stderr`, which you have not redirected. You need to add `2>nul` or (preferably) `2>&1`.

Comment: Hadn't known about 2>&1, that's pretty neat. Does it work on Unix as well as Windows?

Comment: Yes it works also in Unix/Linux. Does also work in PowerShell which has more output streams (Warning, Verbose, Debug, Informational). To catch them all PoSh accepts a wildcard like `*>&1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Running .BAT in minimized**

1. Create a shortcut to the .BAT File. To do so, right click on the file, click Send To, Desktop (create shortcut)
2. Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties
3. In the Run: drop down, choose Minimized
4. Click OK

**Or You have use VB Script**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\_atlassian\Bamboo\BambooConsole.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Save as .vbs Extension and Put in Task Scheduler

Comment: The shortcut doesn't have to be on the desktop. Given this is made for a scheduled task, OP likely does not want an additional useless shortcut on their desktop. However, if OP places the shortcut in shell:startup, the use for a scheduled task is removed which is preffered.

Comment: Shortcut no required. You are right